# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get a Tv show to display on multiple cards. I'm just using one Tv show before I start adding any more. So it should basically display one tv show on all the cards.

The error is coming from the tvList.js.

tvList.js

```
import React from "react";
import Tv from "../tvCard/";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const TvList = (props) => {
  let tvCards = props.tvshows.map((m) => (
    <Grid key={m.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} xl={2}>
      <Tv key={m.id} tv={m} />
    </Grid>
  ));
  return tvCards;
};

export default TvList;
```

The Tv card seems to be fine and is working in my storybook.

tvCard.js

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import CalendarIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CalendarTodayTwoTone";
import StarRateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/StarRate";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import img from '../../images/tv-poster-placeholder.png'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  card: { maxWidth: 345 },
  media: { height: 500 },
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  },
});

export default function TvCard(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const tv = props.tv;
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardHeader className={classes.header} title={tv.name} />
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={
          tv.poster_path
            ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${tv.poster_path}`
            : img
        }
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="p">
              <CalendarIcon fontSize="small" />
              {tv.first_air_date}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="p">
              <StarRateIcon fontSize="small" />
              {"  "} {tv.vote_average}{" "}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites" onClick={null}>
          <FavoriteIcon color="primary" fontSize="large" />
        </IconButton>
        <Button variant="outlined" size="medium" color="primary">
          More Info ...
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

tvPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../components/headerTvList";
import FilterCard from "../components/filterTvCard";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TvList from "../components/tvList";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    padding: "20px",
  },
});

const TvListPage = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const tvshows = props.tvshows;

  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Header title={"Discover Tv Shows"} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item container spacing={5}>
        <Grid key="find" item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} xl={2}>
          <FilterCard />
        </Grid>
        <TvList tvshows={tvshows}></TvList>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default TvListPage;
```

src/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TvPage from "./pages/tvPage";

const sample = {

  "backdrop_path": "/wAEWZm2pSopAbqE5dQWE0ET8aR5.jpg",
  "first_air_date": "2021-01-08",
  "genre_ids": [
      10759,
      10765,
      99
  ],
  "id": 114695,
  "name": "Marvel Studios: Legends",
  "origin_country": [
      "US"
  ],
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_name": "Marvel Studios: Legends",
  "overview": "Revisit the epic heroes, villains and moments from across the MCU in preparation for the stories still to come. Each dynamic segment feeds directly into the upcoming series — setting the stage for future events. This series weaves together the many threads that constitute the unparalleled Marvel Cinematic Universe.",
  "popularity": 140.788,
  "poster_path": "/EpDuYIK81YtCUT3gH2JDpyj8Qk.jpg",
  "vote_average": 7.6,
  "vote_count": 515
}
        
    
    
      const tvshows = [sample, sample, sample, sample, sample, sample, sample];

      const App = () => {
        return (
            <TvPage tvshows={tvshows} />
        );
      };
      
      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I suggest that as the props get passed down through each component, you log them out (or use a debugger.)  At some point `tvshows` is `undefined`.

Comment: Add optional sign and check it: `let tvCards = props.tvshows?.map((m) => ( ...`

Answer (score 0):

It could be an with the tvPage component.

```js
const tvshows = props.tvshows;
```

Here the value of tvshows might be empty initially. I'd suggest i your TvList component do an null check.

```
const TvList = (props) => {
  let tvCards = props.tvshows?.map((m) => (
    <Grid key={m.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} xl={2}>
      <Tv key={m.id} tv={m} />
    </Grid>
  ));
  return tvCards;
};
```

The `?` is an [optional chaining] operator(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: In the OP, the value is not initially empty.  It's a static array.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that for some reason, `props.tvshows` is undefined within `TvList`, even though it should be passed down from `App` to `TvPage` to `TvList`. At some point down the line, `tvshows` is lost.

I would suggest logging all instances of `tvshows`, starting from when it is first defined in `App`, then logging in `TvPage`, then `TvList`, to see where exactly the problem is coming from. Once you've found it, do some debugging to make the problem stop.